# Data.Memocombinators not catching cases in presence of extra variable

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming

Consider the two functions below. `traceShow` has been included to show DP cache hits or misses. The first one has been poached from the [MemoCombinators documentation](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=data.memocombinators&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=data.memocombinators+memo2). The second I constructed myself.

```
import Data.MemoCombinators as Memo
import Debug.Trace

fib :: Int -> Int
fib = Memo.integral fib'
    where
        fib' :: Int -> Int
        fib' 0 = traceShow 0 $ 0
        fib' 1 = traceShow 1 $ 1
        fib' n = traceShow n $ fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)    

brokenFib :: a -> Int -> Int
brokenFib a = Memo.integral brokenFib'
    where
        brokenFib' :: Int -> Int
        brokenFib' 0 = traceShow 0 $ 0
        brokenFib' 1 = traceShow 1 $ 1
        brokenFib' n = traceShow n $ brokenFib [] (n-1) + brokenFib [] (n-2)
```

`fib` takes advantage of the DP, but `brokenFib` doesn't, meaning the extra variable must be messing it up somehow. It's not hard to construct an scenario where you'd want to DP only one of the arguments of a two argument function, but that can't be done without finding out how the extra variable is messing with `brokenFib`. Any advice?

edit:

Implementation of the second solution given by @user6655594:

```
brokenFib :: a -> Int -> Int
brokenFib = Memo.memoSecond Memo.integral brokenFib'
    where
        brokenFib' :: a -> Int -> Int
        brokenFib' _ 1 = traceShow 1 $ 1
        brokenFib' _ 2 = traceShow 1 $ 1
        brokenFib' _ n = traceShow n $ (brokenFib [] (n-1)) + brokenFib [] (n-2)
```

It doesn't catch DP either, although the documentation ("Memoize the second argument of a function") suggests that it should.

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example? This one is too simplified (the argument `a` is not used anywhere) and it's unclear what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out this very question was discussed on #haskell three years ago.
Have a look at these chat events:

- efie: [15695230](http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=15695230&timestamp=1368546348#t1368546348) (references lpaste http://lpaste.net/87973 )
- int-e: [15695262](http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=15695262&timestamp=1368546806#t1368546806)
- efie: [15695288](http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=15695288&timestamp=1368547255#t1368547255)
- int-e: [15695302](http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell?id=15695302&timestamp=1368547433#t1368547433)

Based on int-e's remarks, it appears that `memoSecond integral f` by itself is not
that useful. I think that it is meant to be used so you can specify how the
second argument should be memoized. In other words, you should always memoize
on both function arguments, and `memoSecond` is provided so you can specify a
strategy for memoizing on the second argument. Thus, int-e suggests something
like:

```
integral (memoSecond integral f)
```

Of course, each `integral` may be replaced with a different memoization
strategy.

Moreover, what actually happens can depend on how you write the function
and whenter you run it using ghci or compile it with ghc and what
optimization level you use.

Consider this program:

```
import qualified
  Data.MemoCombinators as Memo
import Debug.Trace

afib :: Char -> Int -> Int
afib _ = bfib
  where
    bfib = Memo.integral cfib
    cfib n | trace msg False = undefined
      where msg = "cfib at " ++ show n
    cfib 1 = 1
    cfib 2 = 2
    cfib n = bfib (n-1) + bfib (n-2)

main = do print (afib 'x' 5); print (afib 'x' 6)
```

and a second version where the line `afib _ = bfib` is changed to `afib = \_ -> bfib` (all other lines are the same.)

Whether afib is memoized can depend on how you execute / compile it:

```
            afib _ = bfib | afib = \_ -> bfib 
           ---------------|-------------------
ghci        NOT MEMOIZED  | MEMOIZED
runhaskell  NOT MEMOIZED  | MEMOIZED
ghc         NOT MEMOIZED  | MEMOIZED
ghc -O2     MEMOIZED      | MEMOIZED
```

So, in this case it appears you should use the second form to guarantee
memoization.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `fib` is a value that doesn't change - it's a memoized function and the memoized values are shared between invocations.

On the other hand `brokenFib` is a function that for each invocation with a value of type `a` creates a new memoized function, which doesn't share memoized values with the others.

You have several options (I didn't test any of them and I'm not that familiar with the package):

- Use `memoSecond` to memoize the second argument, something like

  ```
  brokenFib = memoizeSecond integral brokenFib'
    ...
  ```

  although the docs don't seem to describe how is the first argument handled.
- Memoize both arguments with `memo2`, if possible.
- If the first argument of type `a` is the same throughout the whole invocation, you can use

  ```
  brokenFib a = go
    where
      go = integral go'
      go' = ... -- and calls 'go', not 'brokenFib' for recursive calls!
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! Let's assume I'll need to change the extra parameter, so I can't bring it out of scope. I modified the line to be `brokenFib = Memo.memoSecond Memo.integral brokenFib` (and modified `brokenfib'` to have an extra _ before the actual parameter), but it has the same issue, any advice?

Comment: @user6653296 - Please just show us what you are doing in your question. Also, if this is an answer to your original question, just accept it and ask a follow-up in a new question.

Comment: @user6653296 Let's look at this from the perspective of implementing such memoization function: If you know nothing about `a`, you even can't compare such values, how would you memoize a function of typr `a -> Int -> b`? There is no way. So I believe the solution is what also the other answer suggests: Memoize both arguments. What is the type of the first argument? I'm sure it's not just completely polymorphic, unknown type `a`.